# BeautifulSoup - findall on parent child tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using bs4.

Say within a soup of HTML there's:

```
<li><strong>some text</strong></li>
```

I want to do a `find_all` that will find it. Of course `find_all('li')` works but there must be a way to specify finding  parent child combinations.

Answer (score 10):

I think [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) is what you are asking about:

```
soup.select('li > strong')
```

This would find all `strong` tags that are direct children of `li` tags.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = "<li><strong>some text</strong></li>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.select('li > strong')
[<strong>some text</strong>]
```

Comment: @user1325143 please see if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = "<li><strong>some text</strong></li>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('li')
<li><strong>some text</strong></li>
>>> soup.find('li').find('strong')
<strong>some text</strong>
>>> soup.find('li').find('strong').text
u'some text'
>>>
```